# paragraph tag does not enclose block elements

Tags: html, css

How do I place block elements in the HTML paragraph tag? When I attempt to do that, Firebug's HTML tab shows that the paragraph does not enclose the block element. Furthermore, any CSS applied to the paragraph does not apply to the child block element.

This code:

```
<p>
 <ol>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
 </ol>
</p>

p {
 line-height: 2em;
}
```

Becomes rendered as:

```
<p></p>
<ol>
 <li>foo</li>
 <li>bar</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If you are considering wrapping content around a list, put a paragraph before the list, and another after it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html:

> The P element represents a paragraph.
>   It cannot contain block-level elements
>   (including P itself).

Comment: Is P the only tag with this strange rule? Is the rule overridable with CSS?

Comment: I found this for your question http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?820558-Some-Block-level-elements-cannot-contain-Block-elements

Answer (score 1):

List tags are not supposed to be enclosed in a paragraph tag. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using a `<div>` instead of a `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs are meant to hold inline elements not block elements. In fact, take a peek at this...

http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/153770-acceptable-put-ul-inside-paragraph.